# CRM Online 2013 and SQL Azure Integration

Tags: azure, reporting-services, ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using CRM Online 2013 and I have to do reporting with custom code and there are reports that just cannot be done with Fetch XML. So my question is.

1. Can I use Azure integration with CRM Online 2013 to extract CRM data of entities into SQL Azure through some ETL tool like `SSIS` or any other (recommend please) and do the reporting through SSRS from SQL Azure?
2. If yes, then we come to our second step. Is there a way to call these reports from CRM Online? I know we can't upload the `.rdl` files with custom code to CRM Online. So I am thinking of calling the reports from CRM even though the reports may reside on Azure server.

Its the second step I am most worried about as being impractical. Suggestions?

Comment: So CRM is your Source and Azure is your destination? or vise versa?

Comment: crm online is the source and azure is the source. I wrote a script in C# and transferred the data from crm to azure. Now i can do reporting in SQL.